# How to get all the compilation error messages in Angular terminal?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a component in `app.module.ts`, which I created.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      <new component>],
```

But then the terminal start showing a lot of errors:

[image]

The error is definitely not on the error message that shows up in the terminal, as everything is okay if I don't add the new component in the declaration.
When I scroll up to see the first error message, it was truncated because it's too long. Is there any way to save the compilation error to a file so I can see?

Comment: the reason it does not show it before you add it to your app module is because it is not a compilation error but a binding error, you have a problem with your bindng in dxo-font component, you should probably do it like that:<dxo-font [color]="getlabelAxixColor()"> and make sure you have an input() variable named color in your dxo-font.component.ts

Comment: No, I'm sure it's not a binding error. the new component got nothing to do with dxo. Dxo is in other component. This error just show up when I add the new component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/redirect-output-from-command-line-to-text-file/) you can redirect all output writes to the same file. Just try the following;

```
ng serve 1> log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: This is very close to what I did. When I used `&1`, I got the following error `The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.`. I just changed &1 to some other filename and it works.